# Why can't I declare a public method in an interface?

Tags: c#, .net

Why doesn't the compiler like that I declare a public method in a class interface (this caused the error I got here [.NET Class Interface, Inheritance and Library: error does not implement interface member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729153/net-class-interface-inheritance-and-library-error-does-not-implement-interface)).

Is it just because of syntax or because of something more fundamental ?

OK it's implicit but why would it hurt to make it explicit ?

Comment: A "class interface"?

Answer (score 57):

Interface is a contract and anywhere where you can access the interface, you should be able to access all the methods in it. In other words, all the methods declared in the interface are supposed to be public so it doesn't make sense stating it explicitly.

Comment: OK it's implicit but why would it hurt to make it explicit.

Comment: IMHO you should only have to specify something when there is an alternative. E.g.: a field can either be private, public, protected and/or internal so specifying one of these is more clear than relying on the default. When there is no alternative, why specify it? This is one of the reasons I dislike VB.NET, keywords such as Function and Sub are so redundant and clutter my code adding nothing.

Comment: Yea, but you have to put `static` in methods of a static class... even though they can only be static. Why not the same for interfaces?

Answer (score 18):

Since C# 8 things are a bit different. `public` modifier is now allowed. I suggest reading [this article](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/11/c-8-interfaces-public-private-and.html).

Answer (score 8):

Interface methods are implicitly public so declaring them public is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

[Check this out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/10/don-t-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static.aspx)

Thought it is for constants, I think this is what language designers were thinking why not to permit Public in interface.

Comment: The link in this answer seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any access modifiers in interfaces (e.g. private, partial). This is because it's the implementing class's responsibility to mark the accessibilty of the methods. It keeps the purpose of interfaces singular, which is to define the signature of the class, not to define its access restriction.